# Finding the leftmost node in a tree in F#

Tags: f#, binary-tree

The goal of the function is to find and return the value in the left most node in the tree:

```
type btree = Empty | Node of btree * int * btree

type finding = NotFound | Found of int

let s = Node (Node(Empty, 5, Empty), 3, Node (Empty, 6, Empty))
(*
     (3)
    /   \
  (5)    (6)
  / \    / \
 () () ()  ()

                *)

let rec leftmost t =
    match t with
    Node (t, _, _) -> leftmost t
    | _ -> failwith "Empty"


let n = leftmost s
printfn "Found %i" n
```

This is how I currently have my code. It does run into the empty tree error everytime. I am new to F# and am having difficulty figuring out how to implement the case when I do find the leftmost node. 
my initial thought was

```
   | (Empty, t, _) -> t
```

but I am finding no success, any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost there. The idea with the `| (Empty, )` guard is good. If applied at the correct position, it works:

```
let rec leftmost t =
    match t with
    Node(Empty, n, _) -> n
    | Node (t, _, _) -> leftmost t
    | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```

The important part is, that we need to stop at the current node `t` and return its payload `n`, once the next left child is `Empty`.

---

For completeness: I'd recommend to name the left subtree diferently than the current root and align the cases:

```
let rec leftmost t =
    match t with
    | Node(Empty, n, _) -> n
    | Node (l, _, _) -> leftmost l
    | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```

Also, there's a shortcut for `let f x = match x with | P`: `let f = function | P`, which alleviates the need to come up with a name for the parameter:

```
let rec leftmost = function
    | Node(Empty, n, _) -> n
    | Node (l, _, _) -> leftmost l
    | _ -> failwith "Empty"
```